# Установка кнопкам ссылок на публикацию в соцсетях другой страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице имеется слайдер со списком видео материалов (просто видео). Для примера так выглядит элемент:

```
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">
  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?id_video_on_youtube" class="holder fancybox fancybox.iframe various iframe preview video-link" data-post-link="/video/link_on_page_with_video">
    <img class="swiper-slide-fon" src="//img.youtube.com/vi/id_video_on_youtube/mqdefault.jpg">
    <div class="multimedia row">
      <i class="flaticon-multimedia col align-self-center"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

При клике по блоку-слайду открывается окно fancybox, в котором открывается видео. После загрузки окна fancybox я добавляю иконки соцсетей, а после закрытия убираю их:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function() { addSocialInFancyboxVideo() },
  afterClose: function() { removeSocialInFancyboxVideo() },
});
```

При выводе иконок мне необходимо оборачивать это в тег `a` с ссылкой на публикацию в зависимости от соцсети. Реализовал примерно так - проходимся в цикле по иконкам и оборачиваем их методом `wrap` в тег `a` с ссылкой которую получаем при помощи функции:

```
function SocialUrl( socialNetwork, link, title, image ) { 
    switch (socialNetwork) {
        case 'Facebook':
            url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?';
            url += 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname + link);
            url += '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
            url += '&image' + encodeURIComponent(image);
            url += '&noparse=false';
            return url;
            break;

        case 'Vkontakte':
            url = 'https://vk.com/share.php?';
            url += 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname + link);
            url += '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
            url += '&description' + encodeURIComponent(' ');
            url += '&image' + encodeURIComponent(image);
            url += '&noparse=false';
            return url;
            break;

        case 'Odnoklassniki':
            url  = 'https://connect.ok.ru/offer?';
            url += 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname + link);
            url += '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
            url += '&description' + encodeURIComponent(' ');
            url += '&imageUrl' + encodeURIComponent(image);
            return url;
            break;
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно получить data атрибуты (и не только) с конкретного видео что запустилось? Может логически поможете все это построить, в голове просто не укладывается.

Comment: Ладно, попробую упростить вопрос. Каким образом можно определить элемент по которому кликнув запустили модалку fancybox?

Comment: Нашел `afterShow: function( instance, slide ) {
    console.info( slide.opts.$orig );
}`